# libimobiledevice is not recognizing iDevice

Tags: usb, ipod, media

I have libimobiledevice-utils installed, and Ubuntu will not recognize my iDevice. I have manually run usbmuxd as root to make sure it operates and it does, but running `lsusb` shows no Apple device. Here's the output from that command:

```
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 0cf3:311d Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f2:b370 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 138a:003d Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The iDevice itself claims that it is plugged in (e.g. - the charging symbol appears), so I assume there is no problem with connection. usbmuxd and libimobiledevice-utils are up to date. The iPod has been wiped and activated as a new iPod over the internet. Do I need to "turn on" libimobiledevice-utils or something?

Ubuntu 15.04 (64 bit)

HP ProBook

iDevice refers to iPod 3G

EDIT: Just tried a new cable, turns out the third party cable I was using is only capable of power transfer and not data. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `lsusb` doesn't list the corresponding device then the device is not properly connected. Check the cable and the jacks on the device and host.

Comment: Turns out my cable was for power transfer only. Good to go. Thanks!